# WPF Grid Row Height = Column Width

Tags: wpf

I'm new to WPF and I'm trying to do following:

- I want to set the `Column0` width equal to the `Row0` height.
- The width of all the columns should be same.
- The height/width of grid should not be constant.

But the Grid height is not becoming same as the Grid width.
Here is my WPF Grid code:

```
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Column0" Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="Row0" Height="{Binding ElementName=grid,
            Path=ColumnDefinitions[0].Width}" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could manage the size with a control situated at Row 0 / Column 0 in the Grid:

```
<Grid x:Name="LeGrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Row="0"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Width="{Binding ElementName=LeGrid, Path=ColumnDefinitions[0].Width}"
           Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualWidth}"
           Content="First" />

</Grid>
```

Comment: It worked. Could you tell me how can i set the window property in such a way that the user can only resize the form from bottom right corner and form height increase proportionally  to the form width like iobit uninstaller.

Comment: You realise this is another question? Anyhow.  The simplest way to stop edges resizing is to set windowstyle=none. You may not like losing the chrome though. It's more involved if you wish to retain the heading etc. To retain proportions you could handle the  SizeChanged event of the window. See how it's changed and set the height/width to match your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The way I usually do something like this is to use a rectangle. I set the fill to transparent, it's blue here so you can see it working.

```
<Grid Name="grid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Column0" Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=measurer, Path=ActualWidth}" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Name="measurer"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: It worked and i think it the best solution until now. Could you tell me how can i set the window property in such a way that the user can only resize the form from bottom right corner and form height increase proportionally to the form width like iobit uninstaller.